# add email validation prior to submitting on php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, forms

I have the following simple form that I am trying to get the email validation error to 
show up within the form to show the error prior to submitting.

Is there a way to do this with PHP or do I have to use JSON?

If I have to use JSON, can anyone show me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

form.html:

```
<form method="post" name="form" action="form.php">
<p>Robot: <input type="text" name="robot" ></p> 
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" ></p>
<p>Email:    <input type="email" name="email"></p>
<p>Phone:    <input type="telephone" name="phone"></p>
<p>Message:  <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send Form"></p>
</form>
<div id="error"></div>
```

form.php

```
<?php

// send to and from
$to = "email@example.com";
$headers = "From: email@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: email@example.com \r\n";

// form inputs
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$robot = $_POST['robot'];

// email message
$email_subject = "Web Contact Message";

$email_body =   
"A message from your website contact form \n\n".
"Email: $email \n\n".
"Phone: $phone \n\n".
"From: $name \n\n".
"Message: \n". 
"$message \n";

// honeypot
if($robot)
header( "Location: http://www.example.com/nothankyou.html" );
    else{

//validate email
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
 {
 echo '<div id="error">Please Enter a Valid Email</div>';
 }
else
 {

// send it
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); 
 header( "Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html" );

 }  
 }   
?>
```

Comment: You can use JS/Ajax. There are plenty of working demos out there.

Comment: If you are doing validation before submitting you wont be using JSON. You'd be checking the values via javascript then once validation is complete turn the data into json to send into your action.

Comment: I had prepare JS validator so you can try use it maybe it can help you solve the problem in easy way :) https://github.com/softdream/wfvalidator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a javascript/jquery plugin to do your front end validation (ex. http://jqueryvalidation.org/, http://bootstrapvalidator.com/). If you still wanted to keep your existing code I'd suggest something like:

First, merge your form.html to form.php
Make sure your php mailing code stays at the top of the file because php headers cannot have any output done before calling them.

```
    <?php
if (count($_POST)) {

// send to and from
    $to = "email@example.com";
    $headers = "From: email@example.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: email@example.com \r\n";

// form inputs
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $robot = $_POST['robot'];

// email message
    $email_subject = "Web Contact Message";

    $email_body = "A message from your website contact form \n\n" .
            "Email: $email \n\n" .
            "Phone: $phone \n\n" .
            "From: $name \n\n" .
            "Message: \n" .
            "$message \n";

// honeypot
    if ($robot)
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/nothankyou.html");
    else {

//validate email
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: form.php?error=email_error");
        } else {

// send it
            mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
            header("Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html");
        }
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
    <p>Robot: <input type="text" name="robot" ></p> 
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" ></p>
    <p>Email:    <input type="email" name="email"></p>
    <p>Phone:    <input type="telephone" name="phone"></p>
    <p>Message:  <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send Form"></p>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["error"]) && $_GET["error"] == "email_error") {
    ?>
    <div id="error">Please Enter a Valid Email</div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: hey AlwaysLearning, I just made an edit to the script. All I did was and an if statement that checks for when a post has been made then the mail logic can be processed.